# Insert seed data at the first time of migration in GORM

Tags: go, go-gorm, auto-migration

I want to insert seed data when `AutoMigrate` creates a table in the database.

When I execute `db.AutoMigrate(&User{})`, it doesn't return any information related to the table creation, so I can't confirm that table has been created, updated, or doesn't do anything.

Is there any way to know the table creation information from [GORM](https://gorm.io/) to insert seed data?

So that I can insert seed data like:

```
if err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{}); err != nil {
    if db.CreatedFirstTime {
        //Insert seed data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [docs](https://gorm.io/docs/migration.html#Migrator-Interface), you can't get the table creation information from `db.AutoMigrate(&User{})`. Try to use `Migrator` with queries combination to get table's info.

For example:

```
if err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{}); err == nil && db.Migrator().HasTable(&User{}) {
    if err := db.First(&User{}).Error; errors.Is(err, gorm.ErrRecordNotFound) {
        //Insert seed data
    }
}
```

Comment: where to add those lines? is it after db.Automigrate?

Comment: @Prieyudha Akadita S - 
If you will be more attentive, you find that `if` operator contains ` db.Automigrate` call.